# Threads don't run simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a simple multi-threading code in which some threads put items to queue and some threads get items from queue:
https://repl.it/@chuoi123/simpleThreading

Full code if you don't want to visit link above:

```
import threading
import queue
import time

def PutWorker(maxValue):
    global item
    while True:
        with putLock:
            if item > maxValue:
                break
            q.put(item)
            print('Added item ' + str(item))
            item += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)

def GetWorker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        with getLock:
            print('Deleted item ' + str(item))
        q.task_done()
        time.sleep(1)

## main process from here
q = queue.Queue()
threads = []
putLock = threading.Lock()
getLock = threading.Lock()
item = 1

while True:
    try:
        numValue = int(input('Number of items in queue: '))
        numThreadsGet = int(input('Number of getting threads: '))
        numThreadsPut = int(input('Number of putting threads: '))
        break
    except:
        print('Input must be ingeter.')

for i in range(numThreadsPut):
    t = threading.Thread(target=PutWorker(numValue),daemon = True)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for i in range(numThreadsGet):
    t = threading.Thread(target=GetWorker,daemon = True)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
```

My problem is putting threads and getting threads don't run simultaneously, so one type run after another base in their order in code. The result of current code:

```
Added item 1
Added item 2
Added item 3
Added item 4
Added item 5
...
Deleted item 1
Deleted item 2
Deleted item 3
Deleted item 4
Deleted item 5
...
```

And I want result like this:

```
Added item 1
Added item 2
Deleted item 1
Added item 3
Deleted item 2
Added item 4
Deleted item 3
Added item 5
Deleted item 4
Deleted item 5
...
```

Why this happened and What I can do for archive my goal?

**Edit**: after try solution in @user68014's answer, I found another way is remove parameter from `def PutWorker()` and simple using global variable there like `item`.

Comment: Python threads do not run simultaneously. They only might seem to if they perform tasks which block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=PutWorker(numValue),daemon = True)
```

You're actually *calling* PutWorker to get the target to Thread. So it's all happening before the thread is actually created. You should be passing in the function itself.

So something like:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=PutWorker, ...
```

No arguments, no call, it's just a function (which Thread will call to start the thread)

Since it has a parameter, you need to "Curry" that in. I'd do it like this:

```
from functools import partial
```

...

```
t = threading.Thread(target=partial(PutWorker, numValue), ...
```

Comment: The usual way of creating a `Thread` with a function that takes parameters is: `t = threading.Thread(target=PutWorker, args=(numValue,))`

Comment: Nice didn't know you could do that!

Comment: nice answer @quamrana. Missed this from python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread